# Why can't you use setData() to set background color of a Cell in QTreeView?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using the following code to try to change the background color of a cell at a given `QModelIndex`.

```
ui->TreeView->model()->setData(index, QVariant(QBrush (QColor(Qt::green))) , Qt::BackgroundRole);
```

where `index` is given by the `dataChanged()` signal.

This isn't working. Any ideas why?

Here's my reimplemented `setData` function.

```
bool TreeModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)
{
    TreeItem *item = getItem(index); //gets item a given index
    bool result = item->setData(index.column(), value);

if (result)
    emit dataChanged(index, index);

return result;
}
```

And here is the `setData` method for the underlying `item`:

```
bool TreeItem::setData(int column, const QVariant &value)
{
    if (column < 0 || column >= itemData.size())
         return false;

    itemData[column]  = value;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `setData` returns true? You use standard model? No custom delegates? `index.isValid()`?

Comment: yes, `setData` returns true, i've reimplemented QAbstractItemModel and I have custon delegate only for column 0 (not for the column i want to color).

Comment: So... please, show a code, where you implement a support for `Qt::BackgroundRole` (and where you keed a data that you set). There are no telepaths here, who can debug your code remotely :)

Comment: you're right, sorry, i've added some code. I don't really know what _implenting a support_ for `Qt::BackgroundRole` entails... perhaps that is my problem? Where and how do i need to do this?

Comment: Just to clarify `TreeModel` is a class you made correct?

Comment: And what is `itemData`

Comment: Yes TreeModel is a class inheriting QAbstractItemModel, `itemData` is a vector from a container class `TreeItem`. Sorry for the vague code, I've found a solution and posted it below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies for the vague question. I've managed to solve it by myself so I will post here in case anyone is ever stuck on a similar issue.

The problem for me was that I hadn't reimplemented QAbstractItemView's `data()` method to account for the new role.

```
QVariant TreeModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
TreeItem *item = getItem(index);

if (role == Qt::BackgroundRole)
     return item->data(index.column());
//and so on...
```

AFAIK the `data()` method gives the treeview the data out of the model that it needs to present. Within this method I hadn't accounted for the case when `role == Qt::BackgroundRole` so the view was never given the appropriate information out of the model.